# Pushing changes to a branch in github

Tags: git, github

Do we need to always push the changes into a branch in the github by making the changes in the latest tag of that branch?

Suppose there are tags version t1 and t2(latest) corresponding to a branch b1. If we need to push the changes in the branch b1, do we always need to make changes in the latest tag?

This is a conceptual question, need an insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to always push changes into a branch by making the changes in the latest tag of that branch. The process of pushing changes and creating tags in a Git repository depends on the specific workflow and version control strategy adopted by the development team.

Tags in Git are typically used to mark specific points in the commit history of a repository, such as release versions or significant milestones. Tags are generally immutable and serve as references to specific commits.

Branches, on the other hand, are used to facilitate parallel development and allow for the creation of isolated environments for different features, bug fixes, or experiments. Developers often make changes in their local branches and push those changes to remote branches in order to collaborate with other team members.